# How to determine whether or not this series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n^{-1/2}}{2+\sin^2(n)}$$

I tried the divergence test but it approaches 0.

It's not a geometric series.

Doubt I could apply the integral test.

Not a p-series nor an alternating series.

Can't use root test.

I suppose I am left with either ratio test or a comparison test but I couldn't figure those out.

Advice?

Comment: Hint: all terms are $\ge \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**  Try using the comparison test and comparing to the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  To apply this, notice that $2\leq 2+\sin^2(n)\leq 3$  so that $$\frac{n^\frac{-1}{2}}{3}\leq \frac{n^\frac{-1}{2}}{2+\sin^2(n)}\leq \frac{n^\frac{-1}{2}}{2}.$$